# mongodb question, looking for a solution - error

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I was trying to run & connect mongodb to my apps, whenever running it i keep on running into this error.

```
\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:694
    throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +      
          ^

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

[image: screenshot of the code]

i kept on trying other ways but can't see

[image: screenshot of the error]

m to figure it out.

Comment: `process.env.DATABASE_URL` is `undefined`. Your `.env` file is in a wrong place I guess

Comment: Please copy the code into the post itself. Don't share images of your code.